# Why does Powershell xml.save create LFs in multi line comments on Windows?

Tags: xml, powershell, newline, lf

I found out that xml.save ends multi line comments with LF on windows instead of CR LF. Why is that? Here is my code

```
    [xml]$myXml= @"
<myTag>
        <!-- multi line comment
        each line ends with CR LF
        in my code, but with LF
        after .save gets called
        end of my multi line comment -->
</myTag>
"@

$myXml.save("C:\temp\my.xml")
```

Here is a screenshot of Notepad++ from my.ps1 to show that my code does not contain any LFs

[image]

Here is a screenshot of Notepad++ from my.xml to show the LFs

[image]

One way to fix this, which I found, is using XmlWriterSettings and XmlTextWriter:

```
$settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$settings.NewLineChars = "`r`n"
$settings.Indent = $true
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::Create($dependencyXmlPath, $settings)
$myXml.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
```

Is this the most simple solution?

Comment: This is actually the .Net XmlDocument.Save() method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=net-8.0

Comment: It doesn't create linefeed, it just uses the linefeeds already in the text.  You have LFs in your input.  Just put everything on one line in your code instead of multiple lines.

Comment: If the comment is one line, it doesn't rewrap it on save.

Comment: @jdweng you are wrong. It creates the LFs. I added a screenshot for proof.

Comment: Your code multiline comment input has 5 lines.  Each line has a return at the end.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you were saying that I had LFs in my input, but you are saying that I should make the comment a single line. I cannot, because I am not responsible for the input xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instruct the `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance to preserve insignificant whitespace before loading**, by setting its **`PreserveWhitespace`** property to `$true`, which **preserves the input *newline format*** as well as the **specific *intra-line whitespace***<sup>[1]</sup> (note how the indentation changed in your output file).

```bash
# Create an [xml] instance explicitly, so that its
# .PreserveWhitespace property can be set *before* loading content.
($myXml = [xml]::new()).PreserveWhitespace = $true
# Now load the XML text (parse it into a DOM).
$myXml.LoadXml(
@"
<myTag>
        <!-- multi line comment
        each line ends with CR LF
        in my code, but with LF
        after .save gets called
        end of my multi line comment -->
</myTag>
"@
)

$myXml.Save("C:\temp\my.xml")
```

However, apart from preserving the indentation, the above only consistently results in Windows-format CRLF newlines *if your `.ps1` file uses them* (which it does):

- The string values resulting from [here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) preserve the *script file's* newlines as-is.

See:

- the next section for an explanation of the problem
- the bottom section for a solution *without* `.PreserveWhitespace` or, even with the latter, to ensure *consistent* use of a (possibly different) format.

---

**Generally** - **unless `.PreserveWhitespace = $true` is in effect** - the **[`.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save)** method:

- ***invariably* uses the *platform-native* newline format**, irrespective of the original input text's newline format...
- ... with **one *exception***, which is the one you ran into:

  - Behind the scenes, the `XmlWriterSettings` instance that the `.Save()` method uses (when *not* passed an `XmlWriter` instance explicitly) has its [`.NewLineHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling) property set to `None`.
  - This results in **newlines that are part of *multiline comments*, *multiline text nodes* and other potentially multiline constructs such as *CDATA sections* getting serialized *with LF-only newlines* - always**, irrespective of the original newline format in the input (presumably because in the in-memory DOM all newlines are stored in LF-only format).
  - This **behavior is certainly surprising, and arguably a bug**, given that it's therefore easy to end up with a *mix* of CRLF and LF newlines on Windows, as in your case.

---

**A workaround *without* `.PreserveWhitespace = $true` and / or ensuring a *consistent* output newline format**:

Note the two use cases:

- You may need need or want to preserve insignificant whitespace from the input on *reading* and are only concerned with ensuring *consistent* use of the newline format of interest on *writing*.
- You need `.PreserveWhitespace = $true` but want to use a *different* newline format on writing.

You can control the output newline format by explicitly creating a [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlWriter) instance with with an [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings) instance with the following properties:

- For pretty-printing - if desired - set `.Indent = $true`, which uses 2 spaces per indentation level by default, overridable via `.IndentChars` - this is what `.Save()` does when given an output file path or stream.
- Set `.NewLineHandling = 'Replace'` to ensure *consistent* use of newlines (this is actually the *default* value, so it is curious that `.Save()` in effect uses `'None'`).

  - By default, this gives you *platform-native* newlines.
  - To use a *fixed* format, use `` .NewLineChars = "`r`n" `` / `` .NewLineChars = "`n" `` for Windows-format CRLF / Unix-format LF-only newlines.

```bash
# Using an [xml] cast means that insignificant whitespace
# is *not* preserved.
[xml] $myXml= @"
<myTag>
        <!-- multi line comment
        each line ends with CR LF
        in my code, but with LF
        after .save gets called
        end of my multi line comment -->
</myTag>
"@

# Create an XML writer explicitly, with settings
# that 
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create(
  "C:\temp\my.xml", 
  [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings] @{ 
    # Pretty-print, using the value of .IndentChars
    # per indentation level; default is *two spaces*.
    Indent = $true
    # Replace all newlines in the DOM with the character(s) 
    # specified in the .NewLineChars property,
    # which defaults to the platform-native format.
    NewLineHandling = 'Replace'
   }
  )

# Save to the target file via the writer.
$myXml.Save($writer); $writer.Dispose()
```

---

###### Testing a given file for the presence of LF-only newlines:

```bash
# Returns $true if at least one LF-only newline is present.
(Get-Content -Raw $myXmlPath) -match '(?<!\r)\n'
```

---

<sup>[1] There is one **exception**: *intra-tag* whitespace is *not* preserved, i.e. the specific whitespace - including any newlines - that separates the element name from the first attribute as well as the whitespace between attributes isn't preserved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75773106/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted a screenshot of "my.ps1" to proof that there are no LFs. Your combination of `PreserveWhitespace` and `LoadXml` indeed fixes the issue.

Comment: @js2010, yes, but that is (a) cumbersome and (b) in general is only an option for comments, not also for multiline _text nodes_ and other multiline constructs such as CDATA sections.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have the comment marks on every line.  (Usually an editor like the ISE or Notepad++ or Emacs has column based commands for inserting text.)  A long comment line won't get rewrapped after saving.  This is how it gets reformatted after a save.  (`<?ignore ... ?>` has the same problem as the question.)

```
<myTag>
  <!-- multi line comment           -->
  <!-- each line ends with CR LF    -->
  <!-- in my code, but with LF      -->
  <!-- after .save gets called      -->
  <!-- end of my multi line comment -->
</myTag>
```

Comment: This does avoid the LF-only problem, but is (a) cumbersome and (b) in general is only an option for comments, not also for multiline _text nodes_ and other multiline constructs such as CDATA sections.

Comment: Your `<?ignore ... ?>` example, i.e. a _processing instruction_, is indeed another example of a multiline construct affected by the LF-only problem.

Comment: In my case it does not help me, because I am not creating the input .xml files. I could reformat them, but I`d rather prefer to leave them as their are.